# Homework problem on Java: I'm trying to run my program, it shows no error however when I try to run it it doesn't work?

Tags: java, netbeans, java.util.scanner

My homework is to create a program that tells how many calories you consumed depending on the numbers of cookies you ate. But when I run the program, it doesn't show anything and I need it to work for my homework.

Here's the code for more context:

```
package cookie.calories;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CookieCalories {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
        int TotalNumberOfCookiesPerBag = 40;
        int CaloriesPerServing = 300;
        int ServingsPerBag = 10;

        //The next equation represent the number of cookies per servings

        int NumberOfCookiesPerServings = TotalNumberOfCookiesPerBag/ServingsPerBag;

        //number of calories per cookies
        int CaloriesPerCookies =CaloriesPerServing/NumberOfCookiesPerServings;

        Scanner ob2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("This programm can determined how many calories you ate depending on the number of cookie you ate.");

        //Below this sentence, the amount of calories will be determined

        System.out.println("Enter the number of cookies you ate");
        int Cookies = ob.nextInt(4);
        int TotalCaloriesConsumed = CaloriesPerCookies*Cookies;
        System.out.println(TotalCaloriesConsumed + "for the amount of cookies you ate");    

    }

}
```

The program shows me that I didn't made any error in the way I wrote my program but when I play it, it doesn't show anything in the output. Why?

Comment: Could you please explain what this has to do with Javascript and HTML?

Comment: `it doesn't show anything in the output`  :  Do you have the **Output** tab window open to display the "output"? Menu bar: **Window** --> **Output** or hit the **ctrl+4** keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your program I get this output

```
This programm can determined how many calories you ate depending on the number of 
cookie you ate.
Enter the number of cookies you ate
```

when I enter (for example) 4 and press enter I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "4" 
under radix 4
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2264)
    at testasdf.Testasdf.main(Testasdf.java:38)
```

Not really sure why you have "ob.nextInt(4);" instead of "ob.nextInt();" should change your code to be nextInt();

So I am unsure of why nothing is showing up for you, are you sure you have a output screen set up?
What IDE are you using?

Comment: @snow He asked why nothing was showing up, I explained what I had showing up, and a potential error he had as well since he stated he had no error.

Comment: Yes I have a screen set up but it only shows   :   runs Build Successful (total time : 0 seconds)

Comment: @NicolasEspitalier What is your IDE? I would try making a new project and copy in your code and see if it performs with the same issue. This is pretty odd to have 2 answers both running it without issue.

Comment: Apache NetBeans IDE 11.1

Comment: @NicolasEspitalier that is the same version I am using as well. I do not know why it would be not showing any prints.

You have done the code fine to have prints show up, In the least you should have something. including a wait from the scanner.

Comment: @NicolasEspitalier Do you have any other projects open? Is the IDE for sure RUNNING the .java and not BUILDING?


Make sure you click the Run project (projectname) option in the UI (at the top) and ensure its selected the right project. and your project doesn't have 2 main classes or another file with a second main class.

Comment: Alright its finally working thank you for the help

Comment: @nicolas espitalier glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the '4' from the nextInt method params.

`int Cookies = ob.nextInt();`

Also you don't need another Scanner object, you can use the same one to get input from the user multiple times, so you can remove this from your code.

```
Scanner ob2 = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: I did but the problem is still there.

Comment: Weird, your code works on my computer after I removed the number 4

Comment: Where did you run the code? I was on netbeans